# In django-simple-jwt package, how can I conditionally validate a password against different signing algorithms & secret keys?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My use-case is that I have a legacy backend that has generated tokens using an insecure secret key. I have imported all the user data into a new backend using simple-jwt. The app owner does not want to force existing users to logout and login again to get a new token.

The problem is when an existing user requests a token, their old password cannot be checked because the existing hash because it was created with the secret key from the old backend. So I would like DRF/simple-jwt to first try to validate against the default key/algorithm, and if that fails attempt against the old, insecure secret key/algorithm.

Is this possible? Do I create a new serializer class based on `TokenObtainPair` and override `validate`? If so, how exactly would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the backend to your authentication backend in your Django settings:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
        'path.to.first.auth.backend',
        'path.to.second.auth.backend',
    ]
```

In the docs it says:

> Behind the scenes, Django maintains a list of “authentication
> backends” that it checks for authentication. When somebody calls
> django.contrib.auth.authenticate() – as described in How to log a user
> in – Django tries authenticating across all of its authentication
> backends. If the first authentication method fails, Django tries the
> second one, and so on, until all backends have been attempted.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends